# Getting 'PhotoEditorSDK/PhotoEditorSDK.h' file not found' error in react native

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native, photoeditorsdk

I'm trying to install [this](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/quickstarts/react_native) -- `PhotoEditorSDK`, I followed the documentation exactly but keep getting `'PhotoEditorSDK/PhotoEditorSDK.h' file not found` error that causes build to be failed. Just to be clear, this is exactly how I tried to install this framework:

(1) Inside my ios folder, I run command `pod init`

(2) I edit my `Podfile` like so:

```
  platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'nearbie' do
      pod 'PhotoEditorSDK'
  end
```

(3) Run `pod install` command

(4) This is what my `.xcworkspace` looks like after step (3), and I also created `PESDKModule.h` & `PESDKModule.m` files as well as draged `ios_license` license file there, as circled in the picture:

[image]

(5) The content of `PESDKModule.h` & `PESDKModule.m` are copied from demo app's `.xcworkspace` file like this:

PESDKModule.h:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface PESDKModule : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

PESDKModule.m:

```
#import "PESDKModule.h"
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <PhotoEditorSDK/PhotoEditorSDK.h>

@interface PESDKModule () <PESDKPhotoEditViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation PESDKModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(PESDK);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(present:(NSString *)path) {
    PESDKPhotoEditViewController *photoEditViewController =
 [[PESDKPhotoEditViewController alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] configuration:[[PESDKConfiguration alloc] init]];
  photoEditViewController.delegate = self;
  UIViewController *currentViewController = RCTPresentedViewController();

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[currentViewController presentViewController:photoEditViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
  });
}

#pragma mark - IMGLYPhotoEditViewControllerDelegate

- (void)photoEditViewController:(PESDKPhotoEditViewController *)photoEditViewController didSaveImage:(UIImage *)image imageAsData:(NSData *)data {
  [photoEditViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self sendEventWithName:@"PhotoEditorDidSave" body:@{ @"image": [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions: 0], @"data": [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] }];
  }];
}

- (void)photoEditViewControllerDidCancel:(PESDKPhotoEditViewController *)photoEditViewController {
  [photoEditViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
[self sendEventWithName:@"PhotoEditorDidCancel" body:@{}];
  }];
}

- (void)photoEditViewControllerDidFailToGeneratePhoto:(PESDKPhotoEditViewController *)photoEditViewController {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"PhotoEditorDidFailToGeneratePhoto" body:@{}];
}

#pragma mark - RCTEventEmitter

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[ @"PhotoEditorDidSave", @"PhotoEditorDidCancel", @"PhotoEditorDidFailToGeneratePhoto" ];
}

@end
```

But when I try to build the project, I get error like this (located inside `PESDKModule.m` file):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the use of Cocoapods within React Native. Our demo used the manual installation steps, described in [our docs](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/ios/v8/introduction/getting_started). Could you try linking the PhotoEditor SDK using these steps instead of Cocoapods?